# how to measure size of face?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to measure the size of face and eyes on the photo. I am using Python and library OpenCV.

```
import cv2
import os

def find_faces(image_path):
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    # Make a copy to prevent us from modifying the original
    color_img = image.copy()
    filename = os.path.basename(image_path)
    # OpenCV works best with gray images
    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(color_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Use OpenCV's built-in Haar classifier
    haar_classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier('file.xml')
    eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('eyes.xml')
    faces = haar_classifier.detectMultiScale(gray_img, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=5)
    print('Number of faces found: {faces}'.format(faces=len(faces)))
    len2 = 0
    for (x, y, width, height) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(color_img, (x, y), (x+width, y+height), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        roi_gray = gray_img[y:y+height, x:x+width]
        roi_color = color_img[y:y+height, x:x+width]
        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
        for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)
            len2 = cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)
    # Show the faces / eyes found
    cv2.imshow(filename, color_img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    find_faces('Images/face3.jpg')
```

And result of this code is photo with highlighted face and eyes:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usyYE.jpg)

So my question is how to measure face and eyes size in centimeters?

Sorry if this is a bit basic of a question, but for some reason I could not find much online to guide me on this. I have googled a lot, read different articles but nothing helps me.

Thanks

Comment: To get the size of eyes, mouth, etc. in measurable units such as centimeters, etc. You need to have a reference sign on the input image with known dimensions. It will only work if the camera is always at fixed location, then you calculate a factor with known size of the reference sign and use that to get the size of face in centimeters or millimeters.